# Nested Resource for many to many relationship in tastypie. Parent Child relationship

Tags: django, api, resources, nested, tastypie

I have two resources, customer and Phone (I made it simple here by only including few fields). Different customers can have the same type of phone. I wrote my Modelresource class and access the API through  /customer/  and /phone/

Now what I want to do is get the phone for a certain customer. so /customer/1/phone/

These are what my classes look like.

## Models.py

```
# Defines the phone Model

class Phone(models.Model):
    phone_id= models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    phone_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)


# Defines the Customer Model

class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_id= models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    phone = models.ManyToManyField(Phone)
```

## Api.py

```
class PhoneResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Phone.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        resource_name = 'phone'

class CustomerResource(ModelResource):
    phone = fields.ManyToManyField(PhoneResource, "phone")

    class Meta:
        queryset = Customer.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'patch', 'put']
        resource_name = 'customer'
        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = Authorization()

    def prepend_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r'^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<pk>\w[\w/-]*)/phone%s$' %
                (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()),
                self.wrap_view('get_customer_phone'), name='customer_phone'),
        ]

    def customer_phone(self, request, **kwargs):
        # My Question is what goes in this function 
        # I want to get only the phones for the given customer, and exclude other phones that does not belong to them
```

I have looked into http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#nested-resources

But it doesn't work. I keep getting all the phones back, not just the phone that belongs to a certain customer. So if John had an android and an ios, it should return both list, but if John had android it should only return android. But doing this I am getting all the phone in the Phone model.

Comment: What does `customer_phone()` currently look like?

Comment: The only way got it to work was to create a bundle from the customer resource, then remove all the fields besides the phone field, then return that. The problem with this is though, i want /customer to return the phone resource as uri, and /customer/1/phone/ to return full. But I have to either get both as full, or both as uris.

Comment: There must be a better solution than that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Models:

```
class Phone(models.Model):
    phone_id= models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    phone_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)


# Defines the Customer Model

class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_id= models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    phones = models.ManyToManyField(Phone, related_name='customers')
```

Api:

```
class PhoneResource(ModelResource):
    # TODO: update path
    customers = fields.ManyToManyField('path.to.CustomerResource', "customers")

    class Meta:
        queryset = Phone.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        resource_name = 'phone'

class CustomerResource(ModelResource):
    phones = fields.ManyToManyField(PhoneResource, "phones")

    class Meta:
        queryset = Customer.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'patch', 'put']
        resource_name = 'customer'
        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = Authorization()

    def prepend_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r'^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<pk>\w[\w/-]*)/phone%s$' %
                (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()),
                self.wrap_view('get_customer_phone'), name='customer_phone'),
        ]

    def get_customer_phone(self, request, **kwargs):
        try:
            bundle = self.build_bundle(data={'pk': kwargs['pk']}, request=request)
            obj = self.cached_obj_get(bundle=bundle, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return HttpGone()
        except MultipleObjectsReturned:
            return HttpMultipleChoices("More than one resource is found at this URI.")

        phone_resource = PhoneResource()
        return phone_resource.get_list(request, customers=obj.pk)
```

Comment: I gave this a shot, and I am not sure this can work. As you can see the customer model has phone but the phone model does not have a customer. Then how can I can get this customer_set relation. This is the biggest thing I can't figure out! The only thing I can do is phone = fields.ManyToManyField(PhoneResource, "phone", related_name="phone") in the Customer resource. Is that even correct?

Comment: Django automatically adds a reverse relation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/relations/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Comment: Yea ok. I still can't get all the phones for the customer back. Keeps returning all the phones in the model...

Comment: I am not sure what to put in the place of customer_set. Any ideas by looking at my model and model resources?

Comment: I just updated my answer, try that and see if it works.

Comment: Yes. It works now. Although I had to put the path as a string, because I was getting cyclical class import errors. Thank you so much for your help Seàn!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you need separate prepend_urls for that? You can get phone lists for each customer buy adding **full=True** to ManyToManyField arguments:

```
class CustomerResource(ModelResource):
    phone = fields.ManyToManyField(PhoneResource, "phone", full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Customer.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'patch', 'put']
        resource_name = 'customer'
        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = Authorization()
```

Comment: But that will also return other fields. I only want to get phones back. So if a customer had first name and last name , it doesn't make sense to do a call that returns all the fields when I only need their phone. That's why I wanted to do a nested url /customer/1/phone/